# Getting the result array before and after using splice()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've written a demo to remove a specific element from an array via index.

```js
var splice_a = function (array, index) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
  return array
};

var splice_b = function (array, index) {
  return array.splice(index, 1)
};

var test = function () {
  var array = [1, 2, 3];
  
  alert(splice_a(array, 1));
  alert(splice_b(array, 1));
};
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
```

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) says about the `return value`:

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.

It doesn't mention about: if I want to get the result array, should I combine it with keyword `return`?

It should be a case because I'm getting 2 difference results:

> 1,3
>
> 3

My question: what's happen with `return array.splice(index, 1)` in this case?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `return` keyword with a value if you want a function to return that value.

Comment: I don't see what you're misunderstanding here. The code snippet you posted shows the same behavior as explained by MDN. If you return the result of `Array.prototype.splice`, you will get an array of elements that have been removed, NOT the original array.

Comment: @Damon Have you read my question? Same behavior but 2 difference resuls, please.

Comment: It's not the same behavior though. In one you are returning the original array, in the other you are returning the result of a function which does not return the original array, as expressly noted by MDN.

Comment: @Damon Im not sure I understand your mean. `the result of a function`? `the result` is an array, so if I return `the result`, that mean I will get the array, too. Right? Or something....?

Comment: I'll post an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an abstract example of what is happening:

```
// a function that removes the last element from an array, and returns 1
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
  this.pop()
  return 1
}

// a function that removes the last element from an array, and returns the array
Array.prototype.bar = function() {
  this.pop()
  return this
}
```

If you were to call `arr.foo()` or `arr.bar()` the same thing would happen to `arr`, however the return value of the function you are calling is different. Not every `Array.prototype` method returns the array. `splice` for example, does not return the original array. This is analogous to what you are trying to do:

```
function foo_a(arr) {
  // call foo, removes element from arr.
  arr.foo() // We do not return here so the fact that foo returns 1 is not used.
  return arr
}

function foo_b(arr) {
  // call foo, removes element from arr.
  return arr.foo()  // We return the return value of foo here, which is 1
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

foo_a(arr) // [1, 2, 3]
foo_b(arr) // 1
```

**tl;dr**
`return arr.foo()` is basically saying "return the return value of foo" which is always 1 regardless of what ever else it does to the array.

Comment: @HappyCoding no problem, glad I could help! Another way you can think about it is, say you have a function that does nothing other than return a number. If you call that function randomly in another function, it effectively does nothing because the return value isn't used. However, if you return that function, the outer function will also return that number, making use of the return value.

Comment: It's jsut like spaghetti :(

Answer (score 1):

The resulting array is your own array. Don't need to return it back. 
So it just would be:

```
var splice_a = function (array, index) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
  return array
};
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

splice_a(array, 1);
alert(array) //will show 1,3,4;

splice_a(array, 1);
alert(array) //will show 1,4;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will remove `n` data from `m` index of array and returns removed value as an array:

```js
var m = 2,
  n = 3;
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var removedValues = arr.splice(m, n);

console.log(arr, removedValues);
```

So in your situation it will remove one element from array (value at index) and return that in new array.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your functions to show the difference in return values. They will *both* alter the passed in array in the same way. The only thing that changes is the return value. This might be where you are confused. Notice that the `array` variable is changed by `splice_a` before running through `splice_b`.

```js
var splice_a = function (array, index) {
  var removed = array.splice(index, 1);
  console.log(`  Removed = ${removed}`);
  console.log(`  Array = ${array}`);
  
  return array;
};

var splice_b = function (array, index) {
  var removed =  array.splice(index, 1)
  console.log(`  Removed = ${removed}`);
  console.log(`  Array = ${array}`);
  
  return removed;
};

var array = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(`Array before splice_a: ${array}`);
splice_a(array, 1);

console.log(`Array before splice_b: ${array}`);
splice_b(array, 1);

console.log(`Final value of array: ${array}`);
```

As for why you would want to return the value if it is changing anyway. That is mostly for convenience in chaining commands. Consider just the first function:

```js
var splice_a1 = function (array, index) {
  var removed = array.splice(index, 1);
  return array;
};
var splice_a2 = function (array, index) {
  var removed = array.splice(index, 1);
};


var array = [1, 2, 3];
// This will run, because splice_a1 returns an array
splice_a1(array, 1).forEach( _ => console.log(_) )

// This will throw an error, because <undefined> does not have a forEach()
splice_a2(array, 1).forEach( _ => console.log(_) )
```

Comment: I've read your example many times. I understand what you're explaining. But the `final value` is `3` instead of `1` in my example. Im trying to finding the difference.

Comment: I removed the `alerts()`, but if you put them back you would get the same result. Remember `splice_b` is returning the `removed` value, which is 3.

Comment: ya. The difference is: `splice_a` is returning an array and `splice_b` is returning an element (`removed value`). Right?

Comment: Kinda, they both return arrays. `splice_b` is returning the return value of the splice command as you have quoted in your question.